# What does できる mean in this context?

Tags: song-lyrics

[この曲](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNiLTsDIJg0)、「僕に彼女ができたんだ」といいますが、タイトルの意味が分かりません。

★ Even though the song is called 「僕に彼女ができたんだ」, I don't know what the title means.

回答は日本語か英語、どちらでもいいです。

Japanese, English - whatever is cool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This できる means "**to come into existence**".

「僕{ぼく}に彼女{かのじょ}ができたんだ」 therefore means "I've got a girlfriend now." since it would not be natural to say in English the literal translation version "A girlfriend has come into existence for me."

Note that the subject of that Japanese sentence is 「彼女」 and not 「僕」.  Please do not be fooled by the translation: "I've got a girlfriend now.", in which the subject is "I".

More examples:

「今日新しい友だちができた。」

「もうすぐここにラーメン屋ができるらしい。」= "I hear there will be a ramen shop here soon."

「OMG, こどもができちゃった！」= "I/She got pregnant!"  I am sure some of you have heard the word 「できちゃった婚{こん}」 or 「できちゃった結婚{けっこん}」 ("**shotgun marriage**").  It comes from this 「できる」.

Comment: I always thought the literal translation was "I made a girlfriend". Is that wrong?

Comment: That would be 作った. If it were literally "I made a girlfriend" "I" would be the subject

Comment: @ssb Sorry, I didn't mean literal in the syntactic sense,  just as far as the meaning of this できる.